# Padding an image for use in wxpython

Tags: python, icons, wxpython, python-imaging-library, padding

I'm looking for the most efficient way to 'square' an image for use as an icon. For example, I've got a .png file whose dimensions are 24x20.I don't want to change the 'image' part of the image in any way, I just want to add transparent pixels to the edge of the image so it becomes 24x24. My research suggests that I need to create a transparent canvas 24x24, paste my image on to this, then save the result. I'm working in wxpython and was wondering if anyone could guide me through the process. Better yet, I also have PIL installed, and was wondering if there wasn't a built-in way of doing this. It seems like the kind of operation that would be carried out fairly regularly, but none of the imageops methods quite fit the bill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [image.paste](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm) to paste the image on a transparent background:

```
import Image
FNAME = '/tmp/test.png'
top = Image.open(FNAME).convert('RGBA')
new_w = new_h = max(top.size)
background = Image.new('RGBA', size = (new_w,new_h), color = (0, 0, 0, 0))
background.paste(top, (0, 0))
background.save('/tmp/result.png')
```

Comment: Have accepted this as the answer over the numpy approach because it uses PIL, which I've already installed. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with numpy array pretty easy .. something like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
im1 = plt.imread('your_im.png')
im0 = np.zeros((24, 24, 4), dtype=im1.dtype)
im0[2:-2,:,:] = im1
plt.imsave('your_new_im.png', im0)
```

Comment: Good idea. You can use `scipy.pad`, especially if it's not just 2 rows.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure wxPython implementation.

```
import wx

app = wx.PySimpleApp()

# load input bitmap
bitmap = wx.Bitmap('input.png')

# compute dimensions
width, height = bitmap.GetSize()
size = max(width, height)
dx, dy = (size - width) / 2, (size - height) / 2

# create output bitmap
new_bitmap = wx.EmptyBitmap(size, size)
dc = wx.MemoryDC(new_bitmap)
dc.SetBackground(wx.Brush(wx.Colour(255, 0, 255)))
dc.Clear()
dc.DrawBitmap(bitmap, dx, dy)
del dc

# save output
image = wx.ImageFromBitmap(new_bitmap)
image.SetMaskColour(255, 0, 255)
image.SaveFile('output.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
```